# Include pdfTeX in Inno Setup whitout install MiKTeX

Tags: pdftex, installing, miktex

I have developped a little tool in matlab to fill directly some `.tex` files and then compile them in a pdf file (I use the command `pdflatex` to compile).

It is well working on my computer because I have MiKTeX installed.

Now I would like to make a installer (using Inno Setup) to share this tool but I need to include the compiler in the setup. Does someone know if there is a way to only install pdfTeX for the furure users of my tool or do I need to require them to install the whole MiKTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3):

W32TeX is a distribution which is split up into individual archives for specific functionality:

http://w32tex.org/

You can just download the .zip files which meet your needs (Minimal Installation, but I'd suggest adding t1fonts and ltxpkgs) and then run the install program.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use an installed MiKTeX or TeX Live system, because there are several files needed.

So better ask in your installer for the current path to the pdfTeX compiler. Test your installation with both systems, MiKTeX and TeX Live!